# Spring webflux - ServerWebExchangeDecorator code is not executed when an exception is thrown

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have a Webflux application, where I have a ServerWebExchangeDecorator that decorates the request and responses. I have overrides to do some logging and then call the super methods. 
This is what I have in code:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchangeDecorator;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class LoggingWebFilter implements WebFilter {

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(decorate(exchange));
  }

  private ServerWebExchange decorate(ServerWebExchange exchange) {

    final ServerHttpRequest decoratedRequest = new LoggingServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest());
    final ServerHttpResponse decoratedResponse = new LoggingServerHttpResponseDecorator(exchange.getResponse());

    return new ServerWebExchangeDecorator(exchange) {

      @Override
      public ServerHttpRequest getRequest() {
        return decoratedRequest;
      }

      @Override
      public ServerHttpResponse getResponse() {
        return decoratedResponse;
      }

    };
  }

}
```

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequestDecorator;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class LoggingServerHttpRequestDecorator extends ServerHttpRequestDecorator {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingServerHttpRequestDecorator.class);

  public LoggingServerHttpRequestDecorator(ServerHttpRequest delegate) {
    super(delegate);
  }

  @Override
  public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
    logger.info("getBody method");
    return super.getBody();
  }

}
```

```java
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponseDecorator;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class LoggingServerHttpResponseDecorator extends ServerHttpResponseDecorator {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingServerHttpResponseDecorator.class);

  public LoggingServerHttpResponseDecorator(ServerHttpResponse delegate) {
    super(delegate);
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
    logger.info("writeWith method");//THIS LINE IS NOT EXECUTED WHEN AN EXCEPTION IS THROWN
    return super.writeWith(body);
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> writeAndFlushWith(Publisher<? extends Publisher<? extends DataBuffer>> body) {
    logger.info("writeAndFlushWith method");
    return super.writeAndFlushWith(body);
  }

}
```

When I do a happy path with a POST request, this works fine, but when an exception is thrown, the Response Decorator is omitted and my custom code is not being executed.

This is a controller code to replicate the issue:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/decorator-demo")
public class DecoratorDemoController {

  /** The Constant logger. */
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DecoratorDemoController.class);


  @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> postData(@RequestBody String id) {
    logger.info("attempting to post the data");
    if(id.length() == 1){
      Mono<String> created = Mono.just(id);
      return created.flatMap(vo -> Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(vo)));
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("String length must be 1");
  }

}
```

When I post a single character, I have the logs I am expecting:

```
LoggingServerHttpRequestDecorator  : getBody method
DecoratorDemoController            : attempting to post the data
LoggingServerHttpResponseDecorator : writeWith method
```

But when I post more than one character, this is the logs I am having:

```
LoggingServerHttpRequestDecorator  : getBody method
DecoratorDemoController            : attempting to post the data
AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [0b933716]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/decorator-demo"
```

Am I doing something wrong, or missing something?

Comment: that is probably because the exception is thrown (or error is propagated) earlier in the code before it reaches your statement. What does the server 500 actually crash on. If it crashes when sending header data etc, then it hasn't reached the write body part and will obviusly not write the body yet. or log that it is starting to write the body

Comment: The idea behind using a Decorator, was that regardless of how a request is processed (i.e. happy path or an exception thrown), we should be able to execute certain code to log things after a request is done with processing. 

In Spring MVC, the response wrapper work whether the request followed a happy path or an exception occurred. 
In Spring Webflux, I am facing the issue that the response Decorator code is skipped when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Webflux and MVC have a different approach for request/response handling. In your case is handled only correct case logging, if you going to log error cases you can extend AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler and add error body logging.

Comment: here you can read about some common knowledge in how to handle errors in webflux https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors

Comment: Yeah, I have worked with Exception Handlers before. But the idea is to log some metrics and data of every response sent, be it a 200 OK response, or the response that comes from an exception. If can't do this with a Response Decorator, then what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GlobalFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponseDecorator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class ResponseInterceptorFilter implements Ordered, GlobalFilter {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseInterceptorFilter.class);

  public ResponseInterceptorFilter(SqsPublisher sqsPublisher) {
    this.sqsPublisher = sqsPublisher;
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
    DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();
    ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {
      @Override
      public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
        if (!(body instanceof Flux)) {
          return super.writeWith(body);
        }

        Flux<? extends DataBuffer> flux = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
        return super.writeWith(flux.buffer().map(dataBuffers -> {
          ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          dataBuffers.forEach(buffer -> {
            // three byte copies here
            byte[] array = new byte[buffer.readableByteCount()];
            buffer.read(array);
            try {
              outputStream.write(array);
            } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO: need catch?
            }
            DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
          });

          byte[] write = outputStream.toByteArray();
          String responseBody = new String(write);
          log.debug("Response ----> {}", responseBody);
          response.getHeaders().setContentLength(write.length);
          return dataBufferFactory.wrap(write);
        }));
      }
    };

    ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange = exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build();
    return chain.filter(serverWebExchange);
  }

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {
    return NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER - 1; // this is important
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are struggling with this problem where Request or Response decorator doesn't execute if;

- Any `Filter` throws an error.
- Any class in the chain (`router` > `handler`) throws an error which
  is not handled in any of the `.errorXXX()` mapping methods.

Let's see the example below:

```
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomLoggingFilter implements WebFilter {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    ServerWebExchangeDecorator decorator = new ServerWebExchangeDecorator(exchange) {
        @Override
        public ServerHttpRequest getRequest() {
            return new CustomRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest());
        }

        @Override
        public ServerHttpResponse getResponse() {
            return new CustomResponseDecorator(exchange.getResponse());
        }
    };

    return chain.filter(decorator)
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                // do your logging here, this is not the final logging!
            })
            // or
            .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                // do logging here
                log.error("");
                return Mono.error(throwable);
            });
    }
}
```

**Points to note are**:

1. No decorator (`ServerHttpRequestDecorator` or `ServerHttpResponseDecorator`) will execute if any of the Filter or any other class in the link signals an error to the Mono chain initiated for the request.
2. If any Filter or class throws an error it comes to the errorHandler
   of this filter, and once this filter (logging) commits the error to
   the chain then it is caught by the `ErrorWebExceptionHandler`
3. This approach ***only works for Happy Path***
4. Request decorator's `public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody()` method will only be invoked if the incoming request has a body! Means, for `GET` requests or any other requests which do not have a body your RequestDecorator wont even be invoked. So you need to rely on `CONTENT_LENGTH` header and invoke your logging manually! (yikes)
5. You need to handle ***Request & Response logging from your GlobalErrorHandler in case of failure scenarios***.
6. This whole approach of buffering the request and response in the chain *MUST BE TAKEN WITH HIGH CONSIDERATION THAT BY BUFFERING ITS CONTENT THE MAIN PURPOSE OF REACTIVE IS DEFEATED!*

Stack used:

- `spring-boot-starter-webflux:3.x.x`
- Router, Handler & ErrorWebExceptionHandler approach as opposed to `@Controller` and `@RestControllerAdvice`

Kindly correct me, if anyone else has found a recommended/optimized solution to this.