# Spring cloud gateway ServerHttpResponseDecorator writeWith not called on receiving response

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway application and I want to implement a filter which reads the response body before passing it on to the client. Below is the code to the custom filter:

```java
@Component
public class CreateResourceGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CreateResourceGatewayFilterFactory.Config> implements Ordered {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreateResourceGatewayFilterFactory.class);
    
    public static class Config {

        private ResourceType resourceType;
        private String requiredRoles;

        public ResourceType getResourceType() {
            return resourceType;
        }
        public void setResourceType(ResourceType resourceType) {
            this.resourceType = resourceType;
        }

        public String getRequiredRoles() {
            return requiredRoles;
        }
        public void setRequiredRoles(String requiredRoles) {
            this.requiredRoles = requiredRoles;
        }
    }

    public CreateResourceGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> shortcutFieldOrder() {
        List<String> order = new ArrayList<>(2);
        order.add("resourceType");
        order.add("requiredRoles");
        return order;
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            log.debug("Received request at CreateResource filter.");
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(getDecoratedRequest(exchange.getRequest())).response(getDecoratedResponse(exchange.getResponse(), config.getResourceType())).build());
        };
    }

    private ServerHttpResponseDecorator getDecoratedResponse(ServerHttpResponse response, ResourceType resourceType) {
        return new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(final Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                log.debug("Inside response decorator");
                if (body instanceof Flux) {
                    log.debug("Received response from microservice.");
                    Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
                    return super.writeWith(fluxBody.buffer()
                        .map(dataBuffers -> {
                            DefaultDataBuffer joinedBuffers = new DefaultDataBufferFactory().join(dataBuffers);
                            byte[] content = new byte[joinedBuffers.readableByteCount()];
                            joinedBuffers.read(content);
                            String responseBody = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                            log.debug("Buffered response parsed to String {}", responseBody);
                            return responseBody;
                        })
                        .flatMap(responseBody -> doSomething(resourceType, responseBody))
                        .map(responseBody -> response.bufferFactory().wrap(responseBody.getBytes())))
                    .onErrorResume(err -> {
                        log.error("Error extracting resoruce from message {}",err.getMessage());
                        return Mono.empty();
                    });
                }
                return super.writeWith(body);
            }
        };
    }

    private Flux<String> doSomething(ResourceType resourceType, String payload) {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH PAYLOAD
        return Flux.just(payload);
    }

    private ServerHttpRequest getDecoratedRequest(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(request) {
            @Override
            public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                log.debug("requestId: {}, method: {} , url: {}", request.getId(), request.getMethodValue(), request.getURI());
                return request.getBody();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER - 1;
    }
```

I used this [post as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740174/spring-webflux-serverwebexchangedecorator-code-is-not-executed-when-an-excepti).

The `getDecoratedResponse` is the method to create the `ServerHttpResponseDecorator` object. `CreateResourceGatewayFilterFactory` is the filter class and `Config` is the configuration class which specifies the arguments that will be passed to the filter.

The DSL in the `application.yml` is:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/services/'+serviceId.toLowerCase()+'/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/services/' + serviceId.toLowerCase() + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
      routes:
        - id: sample_route
          uri: http://localhost:8097
          predicates:
            - Method=POST
            - Path=/api/resources/**
          filters:
            - CreateResource=DEVICE,SUPER_ADMIN
```

The requests is captured in the filter and the request decorator because I can see the logs, but there are no logs from the response decorator.

The response has an HTTP Status code of `201`.

I need help to understand as to why the response decorator is not triggered.

Note: the intention of this filter is to read the response body. This process can run in a differnet thread as it will not modify the response body before sending it back to the client. If there is a better way of doing this instead of using `ServerHttpResponseDecorator`, pleas advice me. Perhaps a post filter logic maybe.

Comment: Found an answer? Having the same issue

Comment: @Thirumal Nope. I had to abandon this approach.

Answer (score 1):

```js
package com.javainuse.config;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequestDecorator;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponseDecorator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

/**
 * Project: gateway-service-filter-properties.<br/>
 * Des: <br/>
 * User: HieuTT<br/>
 * Date: 04/08/2022<br/>
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoggingWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingWebFilter.class);

    /**
     * Process the Web request and (optionally) delegate to the next
     * {@code WebFilter} through the given {@link WebFilterChain}.
     *
     * @param exchange the current server exchange
     * @param chain    provides a way to delegate to the next filter
     * @return {@code Mono<Void>} to indicate when request processing is complete
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXs347823489349");
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();

        // log the request body
        ServerHttpRequest decoratedRequest = getDecoratedRequest(request);
        // log the response body
        ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = getDecoratedResponse(response, request, dataBufferFactory);
        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(decoratedRequest).response(decoratedResponse).build());
    }

    private ServerHttpResponseDecorator getDecoratedResponse(ServerHttpResponse response, ServerHttpRequest request,
            DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory) {
        return new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(final Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {

                if (body instanceof Flux) {

                    Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;

                    return super.writeWith(fluxBody.buffer().map(dataBuffers -> {

                        DefaultDataBuffer joinedBuffers = new DefaultDataBufferFactory().join(dataBuffers);
                        byte[] content = new byte[joinedBuffers.readableByteCount()];
                        joinedBuffers.read(content);
                        String responseBody = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);// MODIFY RESPONSE and Return
                                                                                            // the Modified response
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                        System.out.println("final value red from : " + jsonObject.getString("message"));
                        jsonObject.put("message", "");
                        return dataBufferFactory.wrap(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
                    }).switchIfEmpty(Flux.defer(() -> {

                        System.out.println("Write to database here");
                        return Flux.just();
                    }))).onErrorResume(err -> {
                        log.error("error while decorating Response: {}", err.getMessage());
                        return Mono.empty();
                    });

                } else {
                    System.out.println("2000000000");
                }
                return super.writeWith(body);
            }
        };
    }

    private ServerHttpRequest getDecoratedRequest(ServerHttpRequest request) {

        return new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(request) {
            @Override
            public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {

                log.info("requestId: {}, method: {} , url: {}", request.getId(), request.getMethodValue(),
                        request.getURI());
                return super.getBody().publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()).doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
                    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                        Channels.newChannel(baos).write(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().asReadOnlyBuffer());
                        String body = baos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        log.info("for requestId: {}, request body :{}", request.getId(), body);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

***I have fixed this issue. The decorated response is invoked with Webfilter and not from Gateway filter.

You can refer this code this worked for me in api gateway.***

Comment: How do you call this WebFilter? I use Java DSL to configure filters and some filters which add information to exchange attributes need to be called before the LoggingWebFilter.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result by ensuring the desired gateway filter is executed before the [NettyWriteResponseFilter global filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/global-filters.html#netty-write-response-filter).
To do this, your filter (not the factory) must implement the `Ordered` interface and specify an order with highest precedence than `NettyWriteResponseFilter` has.

```
@Override
public int getOrder() {
    return NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER - 1;
}
```